# splitting string to array to create dateTime in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string called TheUserTime that looks like this:

```
string TheUserTime = "12.12.2011.16.22"; //16 is the hour in 24-hour format and 22 is the minutes
```

I want to generate a DateTime from this by splitting the string in a array of ints (what happens when it's 0?) and composing the date object.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) with a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) instead.

`ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12.12.2011.16.22", "dd.MM.yyyy.HH.mm", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

`TryParseExact`:

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact("12.12.2011.16.22", "dd.MM.yyyy.HH.mm",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, 
                          out dt))
{
  // parse successful use dt
}
```

Using `TryParseExact` avoids a possible exception if the parse fails, though is such a case the `dt` variable will have the default value for `DateTime`.

Comment: I get "no overload for method TryParseExact takes 4 arguments; what do I need to change?

Comment: @frenchie - What version of .NET are you using? Take a look at the link for `TryParseExact` it details the correct overloads. I missed a parameter. Answer updated.

Comment: I'm using .net 4. I'll let you know how this works; thanks for following up.

Comment: ok, I got it to work. It was (DateTime.TryParseExact(TheUserTimeString, "dd.MM.yyyy.HH.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out TheUserTime)) . Thanks for your help and see if you can update your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would not recommend your approach, but instead use `ParseExact` and specify the expected format.

```
string theUserTime = "12.12.2011.16.22";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(theUserTime, "MM.dd.yyyy.HH.mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: the answer is good but are we to assume that the string theUserTime will be hard coded, I would recommend passing the variable theUserTime = String.Format(DateTime.now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy.HH.mm")); The ParseExact is better because if it can't parse at lease you will know why , in regards to the format..

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12.12.2011.16.22", "MM.dd.yyyy.HH.mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```